# Здраствуйте , не понимаю как делать рендер блока с общей таблицы в корзину(React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

1)я делаю рендер при помощи данной функции
[image: Вот метод которым я рендерю кнопку +]

получается вот это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь я хочу по нажатию на кнопку рендерить определенные данные в блок с корзиной
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот есть пока такая Функция
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том что бы добавлять и рендерить в корзину ту строчку(поля инфы) tr по нажатию на соитветсвующую кнопку

Вот сам масив данных откуда происходит весь рендер
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по индексу добавляйте

Comment: @entithat я нашел способ как присвоить и записать в новый масив данные , сейчас проблема с выводом в блок корзины , вот если не сложно можете подправить https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-franklin-lx5rp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: что-то оно не работает у вас..

Comment: @entithat при нажатии '+' напротив столбца в консоль выводится список того что было выбрано , это сделано для наглядности ,а так оно должно как то рендерится

Answer (score 0):

Функция должна принимать id элемента (у вас id не выставлены, это неправильно), который вы желаете отправить в корзину. Затем с помощью фильтра нужно найти этот элемент и обновить стейт корзины, добавив его.

Comment: можете ли вы дать соцсеть , телеграм был бы очень рад связатся, действительно проблема очень для нужная, спасибо

Comment: оке: https://t.me/enjoythemat